# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 when trying to install pip

Tags: linux, mac, zip, pip, jfrog

I've had this error with pip for a day or two now. Originally, I thought it was a problem with `pip` itself, because it would error out and fail whenever I tried to install a package. So, I uninstalled `pip` with the intention of reinstalling it and trying again Now, I'm seeing the error when I try to re-install with `python get-pip.py`. (Additionally, I've never used JFrog or Artifactory before so I don't know if that could be the problem.)

EDIT: Below, I've included the original error message, which includes a Python 2.7 deprecation warning. Running `python3 get-pip.py` gives me the same issue, but without a deprecation warning.

```
MBP-19-C02ZF9ZDLVDL:~ gabriellabova$ python get-pip.py
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Looking in indexes: https://****@indigoag.com:AKCp5e2gKoGrMKv41KDCjoFdKZLSpkZpHNkfydx3U67PdgUEJwXVVeRpTpU1zoSnuT1wovUWX%40indigoag.jfrog.io/indigoag/api/pypi/pypi/simple
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/ff/g7nk9zzj1cl_b48qw4vsy_w40000gp/T/tmpSOLhyE/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/var/folders/ff/g7nk9zzj1cl_b48qw4vsy_w40000gp/T/tmpSOLhyE/pip.zip/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 382, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/var/folders/ff/g7nk9zzj1cl_b48qw4vsy_w40000gp/T/tmpSOLhyE/pip.zip/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 201, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/var/folders/ff/g7nk9zzj1cl_b48qw4vsy_w40000gp/T/tmpSOLhyE/pip.zip/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 365, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/var/folders/ff/g7nk9zzj1cl_b48qw4vsy_w40000gp/T/tmpSOLhyE/pip.zip/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 311, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    req.populate_link(self.finder, upgrade_allowed, self.require_hashes)
  File "/var/folders/ff/g7nk9zzj1cl_b48qw4vsy_w40000gp/T/tmpSOLhyE/pip.zip/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 225, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/var/folders/ff/g7nk9zzj1cl_b48qw4vsy_w40000gp/T/tmpSOLhyE/pip.zip/pip/_internal/index.py", line 879, in find_requirement
    req.name, specifier=req.specifier, hashes=hashes,
  File "/var/folders/ff/g7nk9zzj1cl_b48qw4vsy_w40000gp/T/tmpSOLhyE/pip.zip/pip/_internal/index.py", line 861, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "/var/folders/ff/g7nk9zzj1cl_b48qw4vsy_w40000gp/T/tmpSOLhyE/pip.zip/pip/_internal/index.py", line 791, in find_all_candidates
    collected_links = self._link_collector.collect_links(project_name)
  File "/var/folders/ff/g7nk9zzj1cl_b48qw4vsy_w40000gp/T/tmpSOLhyE/pip.zip/pip/_internal/collector.py", line 527, in collect_links
    if self.session.is_secure_origin(link)
  File "/var/folders/ff/g7nk9zzj1cl_b48qw4vsy_w40000gp/T/tmpSOLhyE/pip.zip/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 345, in is_secure_origin
    parsed.scheme, parsed.hostname, parsed.port,
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 113, in port
    port = int(port, 10)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'AKCp5e2gKoGrMKv41KDCjoFdKZLSpkZpHNkfydx3U67PdgUEJwXVVeRpTpU1zoSnuT1wovUWX%40indigoag.jfrog.io'
```

Comment: I would not have uninstalled `pip` at all, in the first place. These are tricky things that might mess up the whole place. Also, look at the Deprecation Warning. Maybe you should start with the upgrading of the _Python_ from the Version 2.7 to another one that is also better integrated with `pip`.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai I definitely agree that uninstalling `pip` was a mistake and I should not have tried the re-installation route. And to answer your second suggestion, I have python3 installed and trying `python3 get-pip.py` gives me a similar error message (excluding the deprecation warning). I will update the original post.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with my Artifactory/JFrog setup. After I generated a new Artifactory API key and reconfigured set up my local config, this all started working again.